# Initializing pimp-controller failed: Error binding to tcp://*: no free port in range 9620-9620

Tags: matlab, tcp

The error is thrown from Matlab2020a command window at times when I train DDPG Agent to control over a car in the simulator Prescan8.5 by using Deep-Learning, Reinforcemnt-Learning toolkit and simulink.

```
Episode:  31/ 50 | Episode Reward : 34.55 | Episode Steps:   39 | Avg Reward : 23.60 | Step Count : 6094 | Episode Q0 : -4.89
[DataProvider] ERR: SetErrorState, message: Initializing pimp-controller failed: Error binding to tcp://*: no free port in range 9620-9620
[ControllerIO] ERR: Initializing pimp-controller failed: Error binding to tcp://*: no free port in range 9620-9620
```

I was reminded that the error isn't caused by prescan, so I tried to find out the relevant ports in simulink but failed as a result from unable to search for proper way to find it on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

It isn't mentioned that the prescan supports  the R2019a and higher versions of Matlab in the Prescan producer's official manual, so it's possible that prescan is incompatible with relative higher versions of Matlab.